# Gerar Input dinâmicamente - html , javascript e Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Amigos, preciso receber um valor numérico e a partir dessa entrada, gerar automaticamente os input.

Por exemplo, digito 5, e o programa gera 5 input para entrada numérico.

O que tenho de código é basicamente, um campo para inserir a entrada, tenho conhecimento somente em c# e Java, por isso a dificuldade com html e javascript e Jquery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>     
        <title> UpFlow.me </title>              
    </head>

    <body>
        <body style="background-color:powderblue;">
            <h2>  Adicionar Campos</h2>
        <input type="text" name="visor" /> <br/>
            <input type="button" value="inserir" />

    </body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para criar elementos com JQuery, você pode utilizar do método `append`, e para retornar o valor presente no input, você utiliza do método `val`.

Então no click do botão inserir, pegamos o valor, verificamos o mesmo, pois o input pode estar vazio, caso esteja válido, efetuamos um loop criando campo a campo.

Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#inserir").click( () => {
    let quantidade = $("#quantidade").val();

    if (quantidade) {
      quantidade = parseInt(quantidade);

      for (let i=0; i < quantidade; i++) {
        $("body").append(`<input type="number">`);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>     
        <title> UpFlow.me </title>              
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:powderblue;">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <h2>  Adicionar Campos</h2>
        <input id="quantidade" type="text" name="visor" /> <br/>
        <input id="inserir" type="button" value="inserir" />
    </body> 

</html>
```

---

Alterando um pouco mais seu HTML, podemos criar uma `div` ou um `form` que será onde os campos serão criados, dessa forma nós podemos limpar esse elemento sempre que o botão for clicado, evitando assim a constate soma de inputs:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#inserir").click( () => {
    let quantidade = $("#quantidade").val();
    const campos = $("#campos");

    if (quantidade) {
      quantidade = parseInt(quantidade);
      campos.empty();

      for (let i=0; i < quantidade; i++) {
        campos.append(`<input type="number">`);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>     
        <title> UpFlow.me </title>              
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:powderblue;">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <h2>  Adicionar Campos</h2>
        <input id="quantidade" type="text" name="visor" /> <br/>
        <input id="inserir" type="button" value="inserir" />

        <div id="campos"></div>
    </body> 

</html>
```

Para esse limpeza, utilizamos do método `empty`.

---

Para pegar os valores de todos os novos inputs e somar, existem algumas formas, vou colocar como exemplo uma em que os inputs são criados com uma classe específica, assim com JQuery eu busco todos esses inputs por essa classe e somo seus respectivos valores utilizando do método `each` do JQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#inserir").click( () => {
    let quantidade = $("#quantidade").val();
    const campos = $("#campos");

    if (quantidade) {
      quantidade = parseInt(quantidade);
      campos.empty();

      for (let i=0; i < quantidade; i++) {
        campos.append(`<input class="soma" type="number">`);
      }

      if (quantidade > 0) {
        campos.append(`<input type="button" id="somar" value="somar" onclick="Somar()">`);
      }
    }
  });
});

function Somar() {
  const inputs = $(".soma");
  let total = 0;

  inputs.each( (index, element) => {
    if ($(element).val()) {
      total += parseInt($(element).val());
    }
  });

  console.log(total);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>     
        <title> UpFlow.me </title>              
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:powderblue;">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <h2>  Adicionar Campos</h2>
        <input id="quantidade" type="text" name="visor" /> <br/>
        <input id="inserir" type="button" value="inserir" />

        <div id="campos"></div>
    </body> 

</html>
```

> Referências:
>
> https://api.jquery.com/append/
>
> https://api.jquery.com/ready/
>
> https://api.jquery.com/val/
>
> https://api.jquery.com/empty/
>
> https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Perfeito, no caso para concluir eu precisaria somar as entradas nos novos inputs, por exemplo: temos 3 inputs, entro com o numero em 10 em cada um e retornaria 30.com oque tenho em mente, em c# pensaria em algo como  armazenar os numeros em um array e retornar o resultado, como seria a sintaxe com javascript e jquery?

Comment: @galegoz     `const campos = Array.from(document.querySelector('#campos').children);
    const total = campos
        .map(input => Number(input.value))
        .reduce((acc, cur) => cur + acc);`